# Angular google-map - drawing manager - How get objects?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, drawing

I use at my application angular directive drawing-manager (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools). I would like to get all object, which I have on map, when I press a button save. It is possible? What have to I use? I need save the objects to database and than again draw to map. Or is another opportunity?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is currently no way to do this with the DrawingManager.
[Source](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/942)

Someone will have to take whatever is in FreeDraw and implement into the drawing manager to keep track of the shapes drawn. Good Luck.